# How to create nested select form with closure_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I create a simple_form select field for my Category model that uses closure_tree (https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) ?

I want my select form to be like

```
Category 1
--Child1 of Category 1
--Child2 of Category 1
--Child3 of Category 1 

Category 2
--Child1 of Category 2
--Child2 of Category 2
--Child3 of Category 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Read here: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/Creating-a-selectbox-for-a-form-using-ancestry, it should help.

I tried using this for my input `collection.map { |c| ['- ' * c.depth + c.name, c.id] }` and it works fine.